# Angular polling trackBy doesn't trigger ngDestroy but the component is updated

Tags: angular, angularjs-track-by

In this example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hptdnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.html
without trackBy the ngOnDestroy hook is triggered and the data updated I can understand it

but in this other example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aan45e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.html
with trackBy the ngOnDestroy hook is never triggered and the data is updated without any problem but I don't really understand why! I mean for me the row component if there is
no destroy triggering should be not update without sort of setter on the @Input

Can you explain me, what I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer to your question becomes obvious when you understand what `trackBy` is used for (e.g. https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5): using `trackBy` you are telling angular not to destroy and re-create `ngFor` iterated elements, but reuse them instead. So `ngOnDestroy` is not triggered because components are never destroyed, but reused with new inputs.

Comment: Thanks but the link you have posted doesn't explain how angular handle the input (its all about the items in the dom) Do you know any articles about this topic?

Comment: try this https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/